# How do I prevent service worker from deleting cache, PWA

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I have built PWA enabled SPA by using Vue, js, node technology. Problem is that service worker deletes my stored cache for viewing app offline whenever i switch off my PC, otherwise it works. Second problem is that it refuses to fetch data that includes google fonts, unless I enable CORS in the browser. Since PWA is based on the browser and users will not have CORS add-on installed in the browser, is there some way to enable CORS on the (Windows) server? Thanks in advance, here is my service worker code.

```
// service worker file. Every time when you change this file rename staticCache const in order to changes to be visible when user closes tab and reopens it.
const staticCache = 'site-static-1';  // static cache for main site files, app shell (all static files, html, css, starting images, logo etc). If you change code always rename this to new number 
const assets = [  // this is array of app shell API requests for assets. Those are keys and asset values (images etc) will be values of key/value pair in array
    '/',
    '/index.html',
    '/app.c328ef1a.js',
    '/app.c328ef1a.css',
    '/manifest.webmanifest',
    '/photo-login.04703ebf.jpg',
    '/icon_area.9bfa0c9a.png',
    '/icon_144x144.c75152b5.png',
    '/img/avatar_default.png',
    '/img/icon_pwa.png',
    'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,600,700', 
    'https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js',
    'https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/data.js',
    'https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js',
    'https://cdn.pubnub.com/sdk/javascript/pubnub.4.21.7.min.js',
    'https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/raleway/v14/1Ptrg8zYS_SKggPNwIYqWqhPAMif.woff2',
    'https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/raleway/v14/1Ptug8zYS_SKggPNyCMIT5lu.woff2',
    'https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/raleway/v14/1Ptug8zYS_SKggPNyC0ITw.woff2',
    'https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/raleway/v14/1Ptrg8zYS_SKggPNwPIsWqhPAMif.woff2',
    'https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/raleway/v14/1Ptrg8zYS_SKggPNwPIsWqZPAA.woff2',
    'https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/raleway/v14/1Ptrg8zYS_SKggPNwJYtWqhPAMif.woff2',
    'https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/raleway/v14/1Ptrg8zYS_SKggPNwJYtWqZPAA.woff2'
];  // we hve to fetch separately fonts from links inside fonts.googleapis.com 
// In Chrome Web Tools go to Application>Cache storage and click /css?family=raleway, links are inside value of that key


// installing service worker event
self.addEventListener('install', evt => {
    console.log('Service worker has been installed');
    // programmatically skip awaiting for new changed sw file to become active, because sometimes closing Chrome and tabs is not enough
    // if we change sw.js and want to make sure change is visible ie cache is refreshed, we need to change version number of staticCache constant.
    // NOTE: If we save this file by adding asset to be fetched (image for example) it will be visible in a new cache upon clicking browser reload.
    // ..but if we delete it from the list of items to be fetched, IT WILL REMAIN  in the cache until we change staticCache version number, save  and reload browser page.
    // So it is best practice to always change version number in staticCache whenever you make and save changes.
    self.skipWaiting(); // it will be triggered only if there is a new sw version that awaits to be executed


    evt.waitUntil(  // installing awaits until this is executed first, otherwise it could stop it
        caches.open(staticCache).then(cache => {  // it opent cache, if there isn't it will create one
            cache.addAll(assets);  // add into cache all assets from the assets array []
        })
    );
});

// activating service worker event
self.addEventListener('activate', evt => {
    console.log('Service worker has been activated');
    evt.waitUntil(
        caches.keys().then(keys => {  // get array with keys (of key/value pair) from different cache versions in  Chrome Dev Tools>Application>Cache Storage
            // go thru all caches keys array and delete all values except newest cache, named in staticCache const. That way only the last cache is used by an app
            return Promise.all(keys  
                .filter(key => key !== staticCache)
                .map(key => caches.delete(key))    
            )
        })
    );
});


// fetch event
self.addEventListener('fetch', evt => {
    console.log('SW is fetching data');
    evt.respondWith(  // check if requested data is stored in the cache.
        caches.match(evt.request).then(cacheRes => {
            return cacheRes || fetch(evt.request)  // if item is in cache use it, if isn't go to the server and fetch it        
        })
    )
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the issue is with the `activate` event handler in the service worker. This is mainly using for removing the old cache from the browser. Try replacing the event listener with the following code

```
self.addEventListener('activate', (event) => {
    event.waitUntil(
        caches.keys().then((cacheNames) => {
            return Promise.all(
                cacheNames.map((cache) => {
                    if (cache !== staticCache) {
                        return caches.delete(cache); //Deleting the old cache (cache v1)
                    }
                })
            );
        })
            .then(function () {
                console.info("Old caches are cleared!");
                return self.clients.claim();
            })
    );
});
```

Comment: Many thanks @Rijosh! It works now, even after I restart PC cache file is there. Problem that remains is that after I make a change in sw file, fetch() stores empty cache file unless I enable CORS add-on in Chrome and reinstall service worker..

Comment: I managed to enable CORS for fetching outside files by adding crossorigin="anonymous" into index.html. Like 
<script  src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>. So this question is solved.